# Couldn't convert string to JSON. String to Valid JSON and parse the JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am having the following JSON(invalid) as a string. I need to parse it and get the inner value. I tried a lot but didn't get the result.

```
    $sJson = '{"Place":"MyStore","PurchaseID":"IND.1234-5678-9012-34567","details":"{\"json\":\"{\\\"PurchaseID\\\":\\\"IND.1234-5678-9012-34567\\\",\\\"categoryname\\\":\\\"smartpack\\\",\\\"productname\\\":\\\"bitcoinpack1\\\",\\\"purchaseTime\\\":1504256011148,\\\"purchaseState\\\":\\\"Success\\\",\\\"UniqueToken\\\":\\\"jbbefjifdkpdpajfkomckoof.AO-J1OzEdsZX17M5pAvedDh1Ep_WwlOKamMQN_3O89bRbAPX-uoqPpTJf8EdNcjMhCK1dptGaWReUCSS9JGCJuh6GlAT0l11mkUddo_uJ4YOe8ezYxlmDQ8\\\"}\",\"currentvalue\":\"S270U2J3XF\\/+XnC1ocPp0d\\/Kwf\\/4B\\/\\/tT7urbDn6F+\\/D8j7VD1t8qqwevtKDnAafAtvocPg4Eevkf\\/GZKl1YOgUYyuY63nyekz7GRDuIKVXAZ+iZtPAbwCuwZplUQHaVA\\/EBMjYpPQM0EFtp2WuX\\/Tx9nTnFCtU+gAK4Rg0zLvQNKSJx5WfqhK7wf0wHTTYviTkB\\/pETnkV22oQDIZH9\\/Fy1FXltC7FXHXoMcxtGvkgPSEFOnms4HumjUQ5PtQUbxh\\/oirQeROCAhkO+WKX9WO3bCKjru1uuxspTLCNGJEKAezi2GEBcpFGjq4iS5N7SfO5BOF76\\/joLe3B7OemJNw==\"}"}';

    $sJson = json_encode($sJson,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    $json_array = (array) json_decode($sJson,true);
    $newjson=preg_replace('/.+?({.+}).+/','$1',$json_array);
    var_dump($newjson);
    exit;
```

The Result `$newjson` is not return as JSON Object, it gives as only string.

I need JSON object not a string.

In the given JSON, `json` value is a string(inside valid JSON) which starts with `"`.

I need to remove this.

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: Why do you `json_encode()` something that is already encode? Don't you mean `json_decode()`? And I would use different variable names for the argument and result of this function.

Comment: What you have is invalid JSON...

Comment: It seems to be valid json at jslint.com and jsonlint.com, so you should be able to decode it.

Comment: at jslint maybe but not at JSONLint.

Comment: @Salketer That is what I said, I need to make it as a valid JSON, then I can parse the entire JSON.

Comment: @aynber yup you can check my code in your localhost that the var_dump return value is string not JSON object

Comment: where is that "JSON" coming from? I'm guessing you cannot correct the source huh?

Comment: @Salketer I cannot correct the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is *mostly* valid json, you just need to tweak a few things:

First, replace all of the `\\"` with `"`. (I had to run this twice)

```
$string = str_replace('\\"', '"', $string);
```

Then some of the braces are quoted:

```
$string = str_replace('"{', '{', $string);
$string = str_replace('}"', '}', $string);
```

Once that was done, I was able to successfully decode your json. This could possibly be done faster with preg_replace, but I suck at regexes.

Comment: It worked for me  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a1102f1d2a3f017404ee2b771e80d5a444a7c17e

Answer (score 2):

`json_encode` takes a PHP data structure and turns it into a string of JSON.

You need `json_decode` to go the other way.

Comment: Given string is not a valid. Kindly check with online json editors.